# How to get http responce headers in vue callback without any vue library (axios)

Tags: http, vue.js, axios

I want to get http response headers in the callback of a get request from vuejs. But I couldn't use any library or a third party for this.

there are some third parties like axios, but in my code it doesn't allowed to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch("YOUR API REQUEST").then((res) => console.log(res.headers);
)
.then((data) =>  console.log(data))
.catch((err)=>console.error(err))
```